# Accessing changing arrays in an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object with arrays inside. These arrays have objects that I want to access. My problem is that these arrays contain the next 5 days, so they change from time to time.
The Object:

```
{2022-04-09: Array(5), 2022-04-10: Array(8), 2022-04-11: Array(8), 2022-04-12: Array(8), 2022-04-13: Array(8), …}
2022-04-09: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2022-04-10: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2022-04-11: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2022-04-12: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2022-04-13: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2022-04-14: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

So I want to select these arrays(so I can seperate the days) and after access the objects inside, and that is what I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through all your object and keys using this, then you can do whatever you like to do with the object inside the array. I am assuming your object as **myObject** .

So you can do it in this way,

```
const myObject = {
'2022-04-09': [{ content: "item 12" }, { content: "item 1-3" }, { content: "item 1-4" }, { content: "item 1-5" }, { content: "item 1-6" }],
'2022-04-10': [{ content: "item 2-1" }, { content: "item 2-2" }, { content: "item 2-3" }, { content: "item 2-4" }, { content: "item 2-5" }],
};


Object.keys(dateObj).forEach(key => {
    // key will be each date of your object . like '2022-04-09'
    myObject[key]?.forEach(date => {
    // so myObject[key] will be each array of that object which you can iterate. so you may assume this as accessing like myObject['2022-04-09'] item.
    console.log(date?.content);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have your object stored in `dateObj`, you dont really say what those object contain so I leave them empty. Also you say you have 5 objects in each array but in your example you have 5, 8 or 3 objects inside

```
const dateObj = {
    '2022-04-09': [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ],
    '2022-04-10': [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ],
    '2022-04-11': [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ],
    '2022-04-12': [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ],
    '2022-04-13': [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ]
};

// then you can access each array in your dateObj with this:
console.log(dateObj['2022-04-09']);
// then access each object in array like this:
for (item of dateObj['2022-04-09']) {
    console.log(item);
}

// or you can iterate over all keys (2022-04-09, 2022-04-10, 2022-04-11, ...)
for (key in dateObj) {
    if (!(key in dateObj)) continue;
    console.log(key, dateObj[key]);
    // and access each object in array
    for (item of dateObj[key]) {
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i get "item" and "key" not defined errors.

Comment: `console.log(dateObj['2022-04-09']);` this  does what I want, but the problem with it is that i can't code the date because it changes every day.

Comment: Then the answer below should work.
I just cant imagine what could remove keys in your dateObj, but a simple check should make it work